# get index from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am populating an array of hashes from the database and what I get in the end looks like:

```
[{:element1 => "value1", :element2 => "value2"}, {:element1 => "value3", :element2 => "value4"}]
```

What I want to do now is write the value of element2 if element1 has value1. I tried doing

```
puts my_array[my_array.index(:element1 => "value1")].element2
```

but that only gives me an error saying:

```
no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

What I am using now is

```
puts my_array.find_by_element1("value1").element2
```

but that queries the database every time and I would like to avoid that if possible since I already have all the values.

Edit: my Ruby version is 1.8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `index` for partial matches. Try using `detect`.

```
my_array.detect { |el| el[:element1] == "value1" }[:element2]
=> "value2"
```

Comment: this only works for a single case if you have two values at value1 the code as written will only return one result.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [{:element1 => "value1", :element2 => "value2"}, {:element1 => "value3", :element2 => "value4"}]

result.each do |x|
  puts "#{x[:element2]}" if x[:element1]=="value1"
end
```